# Static ArrayList being empty when called from another class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, static

In classC I read from a csv file and put them into classA object and then to arraylist classB which is subclass of class A

```
public class classC {
    public static ArrayList<classA> arraylist= new ArrayList<>();

    private classC() {
        // do not instantiate
    }

    public static ArrayList<classA> readData(File inFile) {
        try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(inFile);
            String header = reader.nextLine();
            
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                String nextLine = reader.nextLine();

                //System.out.println(nextLine);
                
                String[] tokens = nextLine.split(",");
                String a= tokens[0];
                double b= Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
                double c= Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
                double d= Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
                double e=Double.parseDouble(tokens[4]);

                //store the data in classa object
                classA classa= new classA(a, b, c, d, e);

                //store each object in an arraylist
                arraylist.add(classa);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {   //these prints fine
                System.out.println(arraylist.get(i) + " ");
            }

            System.out.println(arraylist.size());

            return arrayList;
    }
}
```

then in Class B I try to print the array but the arraylist is empty

```
public class classB extends ArrayList<classA> {
    public static ArrayList<classA> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

    public classB() {
    }

    //here is my method to print
    public void printArray() {
        System.out.println("Elements of ArrayList are:");
        System.out.println(arraylist.size()); //prints 0
    }
}
```

in my main method

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inFile = new File("file.csv");
        readData(inFile);
        classB classb = new classB();
        classb.printArray();
    }
}
```

in classA i have neccessary getters setters and toString method to print properly, I can print fine from classC readData method but cannot from classB printArray method.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: In class B, change `arraylist.size()` to `super.arraylist.size()`

Comment: If I do super.arraylist.size() it does not work, it gives me error cannot find symbol variable arraylist

Comment: every time `new ArrayList()` is called, a new *empty* instance is created - the list of `classB` is not related to the one in `classC` (horrible class naming BTW) - and why is `classB` extending an `ArrayList`??

Comment: so classB arrayList is empty because it is instantiated there, so is there anyway to get the arraylist from classC readData method ?

Answer (score 0):

Your class B is not a subclass of class A, it's a subclass of ArrayList. You should probably change its declaration to `extends classC`. After doing that you need also to remove the declaration of arrayList field in classB, because otherwise it will mask the declaration of the field with the same name in superclass classC.

Comment: If I remove declaration of arraylist in classB, how do I print out the array in classB?

Comment: we have no idea what `classA` is (only that it probably has 5 attribtutes) - probably you meant `extends classC`  (as I already commented, horrible class names)

Comment: classA only has constructors necessary setters getters and toString method, there is no arrayList instantiated in classA.

Comment: Yes, you need to extend classC, not classA.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Alex, I did that and removed arrayList declaration in classB and it worked! I only needed to remove the declaration for it to work.